# How to validation select field with php?

Tags: php, html, pdo

I wanna display kategori from database to select option.
If I reload or submit but 'harga' is empty, the error message appear, value of kategori is still "Pilih Kategori". 
How to make value of kategori after reload become 'kategori'based what  I've chose .
This validation works in input field but it doesn't work to select.

```
if($judul_buku=="") {
    $error[] = "Judul belum diisi!";    
} 
else if($id_kat=="Pilih Kategori")  {
    $error[] = "Kategori belum dipilih!";   
}
else if($harga=="") {
    $error[] = "Harga belum diisi!";    
}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="judul_buku">Judul Buku</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="judul_buku" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $judul_buku;}?>"placeholder="Masukan Judul Buku"></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="id_kategori">Kategori</label>
<select class="form-control" name="id_kategori" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $id_kat;}?>" 
required="required">
<option>Pilih Kategori</option>
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_kategori";
foreach ($con->query($query) as $row):
?>
<option value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $id_kat;}?>"><?php echo $row['kategori'];?></option>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</select>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="harga">Harga</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="harga" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $harga;}?>" placeholder="Masukan Harga Buku"></div>
```

Comment: Add a little bit more PHP logic in the option tag to place the word "selected" on the option that was selected, based on the data you received when you rendered the page.

Comment: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html refer the link

Comment: I have used selected but when I reload kategori will be appear  last id.
For example: kategori have 2 record, fiksi and nonfiksi.
And it will be selected 'nonfiksi' after reload. @user2182349

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try it

```
value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $id_kat;}?>"
```